# Problem with order by in MySQL subquery

Tags: mysql

I'm running a query that runs in about 2 seconds when the subquery does not include the `order by date_sold` clause. However, when I add the `order by` clause, the query runs forever.

I'm confused, since it seems that I'm using a index for both queries, and as I've understood, the subquery should be able to use the index for the subquery. Any ideas where I went wrong?

```
EXPLAIN Select buyer_id as bid, 
              (SELECT seller_id
               from sale USE INDEX(tester)
               where buyer_id = bid
               order by date_sold LIMIT 1)
         from sale where seller_id = 35514335;
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+-----------------------------------+--------+---------+-------+-------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type  | possible_keys                     | key    | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra                    |
+----+--------------------+-------+-------+-----------------------------------+--------+---------+-------+-------+--------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | sale  | ref   | seller_id,seller_id_index_asc,sub | sub    | 8       | const | 14933 | Using index              |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | sale  | index | NULL                              | tester | 24      | NULL  |     1 | Using where; Using index |
enter code here
```

The table structure

```
| id               | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| seller_id        | bigint(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| buyer_id         | bigint(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| date_acquired    | bigint(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date_sold        | bigint(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| brand            | text       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| muncipality_code | bigint(20) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| new              | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| car_regnumber    | varchar(6) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| gender           | varchar(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

Tester index

```
| sale  |          1 | tester              |            1 | date_sold        | A         |       14840 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| sale  |          1 | tester              |            2 | buyer_id         | A         |    11768564 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
| sale  |          1 | tester              |            3 | seller_id        | A         |    11768564 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE SALE

```
| sale  | CREATE TABLE `sale` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `seller_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `buyer_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `date_acquired` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `date_sold` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `brand` text NOT NULL,
  `muncipality_code` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `new` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `car_regnumber` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `muncipality_code` (`muncipality_code`),
  KEY `brand` (`brand`(10)),
  KEY `seller_id` (`seller_id`),
  KEY `seller_id_index_asc` (`seller_id`),
  KEY `date_sold` (`date_sold`),
  KEY `tester` (`date_sold`,`buyer_id`,`seller_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=66390336 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=FIXED |
```

Comment: Please add the table structure.

Comment: Does the tester index include date_sold as the first column? if not, MySQL will pull all the rows of the SALE table into a temporary table to order them. And it will repeat that for all 14933 rows of the primary query.

Comment: Thomas, I've updated my question with the description of the tester index, and yes, date_sold is the first column.

Comment: Can you paste the output of show create table sale\G

Comment: @AbdulManaf I've edited the question.

Comment: Have you tried this with an index tester (buyer_id, date_sold, seller_id)? The reason I'm asking is the subquery runs better if the join column is the first column of the index. And I don't remember (it depends upon mysql version) if the order by is smart enough to use the second column in the index.

Comment: @ThomasJones-Low I've previously tried running the query on a index (buyer_id, date_acquired, seller_id), ordering by date_acquired. Bad performance as well. However, the EXPLAIN said it was using "filesort"

Comment: @Thomas is right, an `(buyer_id, date_sold, seller_id)` would work better. You also need a `(seller_id, buyer_id)` index.

Answer (score 1):

## SUGGESTION #1 : Use a Different Index

```
ALTER TABLE sale ADD INDEX tester2 (seller_id,buyer_id,date_sold);
```

I suggest this order because `seller_id` in the query is a constant (35514335). That would make looking up all `buyer_id` values.

## SUGGESTION #2 : Redesign the Query

From the looks of the query, you are retrieving first date_sold for `buyer_id` for `seller_id` 35514335.

```
SELECT buyer_id,MIN(date_sold) date_sold
FROM sale WHERE seller_id = 35514335
GROUP BY buyer_id;
```

If `seller_id` 35514335 has buyers who purchased from other sellers as well, then do this:

```
SET @given_seller_id = 35514335;
SELECT DISTINCT A.buyer_id,B.seller_id FROM
(
    SELECT buyer_id,MIN(date_sold) date_sold
    FROM sale WHERE seller_id = @given_seller_id
    GROUP BY buyer_id
) A LEFT JOIN sale B USING (buyer_id);
```

If you do not want to include `seller_id` 35514335 in the output, then do this:

```
SET @given_seller_id = 35514335;
SELECT DISTINCT A.buyer_id,B.seller_id FROM
(
    SELECT buyer_id,MIN(date_sold) date_sold
    FROM sale WHERE seller_id = @given_seller_id
    GROUP BY buyer_id
) A LEFT JOIN sale B USING (buyer_id)
WHERE B.seller_id <> @given_seller_id;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 1):

As per @Thomas Jones-Low advice, you can try adding two indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE sale
  ADD INDEX suggested_index_1
    (buyer_id, date_sold, seller_id), 
  ADD INDEX suggested_index_2
    (seller_id, buyer_id) ;
```

And please, rewrite the query so it doesn't use this MySQL-only syntax of referencing Select aliases in places that they normally couldn't be referenced:

```
SELECT s.buyer_id AS bid, 
      (SELECT s2.seller_id
       FROM sale AS s2
       WHERE s2.buyer_id = s.buyer_id
       ORDER BY s2.date_sold LIMIT 1)
FROM sale AS s
WHERE s.seller_id = 35514335 ;
```